# Get Text of Template Message Whatsapp Cloud Api

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

According to the Whatsapp cloud Api, you can send a template and get a response like

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "contacts": [{
      "input": "PHONE_NUMBER",
      "wa_id": "WHATSAPP_ID",
    }]
  "messages": [{
      "id": "wamid.ID",
    }]
}
```

Am wondering if i can get the text of that specific template message after it is sent.

Currently what i have is a chat interface that has empty bubbles (from sent templates) and normal bubbles for free form and inbound messages.
And this is not a good experience

I cannot find a place in the documentation that this is mentioned.

This is the docs [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/send-message-templates#text-based)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, I may have misunderstood you, but perhaps getting a template list might work for you:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/whats-app-business-account/message_templates

The response will be A list of WhatsApp Message Template nodes. Knowing the template name, you can get all the information about the template, including the text.